# How to get input in array of class in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, web

I am new to java and this is our first assignment but i am unclear right now that why didnt our teacher passes a array of class object to the Add Student method instead he created array of object as private and just passed the name of the array.How can i add data of students now

```
  public class StudentManagement {
    private Student students [] ;
    private int CAPACITY ;
    private int CURRENT_POSITION;
    public StudentManagement(){
        CAPACITY = 3;
        CURRENT_POSITION = 0;
        students = new Student[CAPACITY];
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student){


    }
```

Comment: This is a common way of performing this type of action. The method accepts a Student object, and the method is supposed to add the Student to its internal data structure, keeping the implementation hidden from the outside world. So for this example, you would likely set students[CURRENT_POSITION] to the object passed in, then increment CURRENT_POSITION. Also, you will need to check that you have not exceeded capacity.

Comment: *Why didn't he pass an array to the addStudent method?* - Method and variable name is **important**. addStudent means that **one** student is being added, not a bunch of students. If the parameter was an array, it would be confusing. Also naming is important, that's why `CAPACITY` and `CURRENT_POSITION` should be named `capacity` and `currentPosition`.

Comment: You seem to have problems with the general concept of object orientation. You should really talk to your instructor and ask him/her to explain the concepts needed for this assignment. Answering this question would a) be to broad b) primarily oppinion-based and c) not of much help. Your instructor can explain this better and faster than we can here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Turing85, Please talk to your instructor to understand the concepts.

This array can hold 3 objects (CAPACITY).

CURRENT_POSITION is where you are going to add your object.

You can try similar to this..

```
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    if (CURRENT_POSITION < CAPACITY) {
        students[CURRENT_POSITION] = student;
        CURRENT_POSITION++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sundararaj

Comment: You can accept this answer, if it helps. Accepting is the SO way of saying Thanks.